# Postfix (Imap) with Dovecot: no auth available

Tags: postfix, dovecot, telnet, raspbian

I'm using Dovecot to get Imap access to my mail server (on Raspbian). I'm using system users and am able to successfully test logins (`doveadm auth test ...`). But I'm not able to get auth option via telnet:

```
sudo telnet localhost 25
Trying ::1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 mail.mydomain.org ESMTP Postfix
```

```
sudo telnet localhost 143
Trying ::1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

I'm missing the `[AUTH=PLAIN]` status, which is mentioned in the [wiki](https://wiki.dovecot.org/TestInstallation).
I don't get any errors on systemctl status.
I don't know what else to try! Can u help me?

Thanks!!

---

My dovecot config `dovecot -n`

```
# 2.2.27 (c0f36b0): /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf
# Pigeonhole version 0.4.16 (fed8554)
# OS: Linux 4.19.42-v7+ armv7l Debian 9.9 
auth_debug_passwords = yes
auth_mechanisms = plain login
auth_username_format = %Ln
auth_verbose = yes
auth_verbose_passwords = yes
debug_log_path = /etc/dovecot/log/debug.txt
info_log_path = /etc/dovecot/log/info.txt
mail_debug = yes
mail_location = mbox:~/mail:INBOX=/var/mail/%u
managesieve_notify_capability = mailto
managesieve_sieve_capability = fileinto reject envelope encoded-character vacation subaddress comparator-i;ascii-numeric relational regex imap4flags copy include variables body enotify environment mailbox date index ihave duplicate mime foreverypart extracttext

passdb {
  driver = shadow
}
plugin {
  sieve = file:~/sieve;active=~/.dovecot.sieve
}
protocols = imap lmtp sieve

service auth-worker {
  name = auth-worker
}
service {
  unix_listener {
    group = postfix
    mode = 0660
    user = postfix
    path = /var/spool/postfix/private/auth
  }
  name = auth
}

service {
  inet_listener {
    port = 143
    name = imap
  }
  inet_listener {
    port = 993
    ssl = yes
    name = imaps
  }
  name = imap-login
}

service {
  unix_listener {
    group = postfix
    mode = 0600
    user = postfix
    path = /var/spool/postfix/private/dovecot-lmtp
  }
  name = lmtp
}

ssl_cert = /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.mydomain.org/cert.pem
ssl_key =  # hidden, use -P to show it
userdb {
  driver = passwd
}
verbose_ssl = yes
protocol lmtp {
  mail_plugins = quota sieve
  postmaster_address = pi@mydomain.org
}
protocol lda {
  ...
}
protocol imap {
  ...
}
protocol sieve {
  ...
}
```

---

My Postfix `/etc/postfix/main.cf`

```
# See /usr/share/postfix/main.cf.dist for a commented, more complete version
myhostname = mail.mydomain.org
mydomain = mydomain.org
myorigin = $mydomain
inet_interfaces = all
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost, $mydomain
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8
#relay_domains =
#home_mailbox = Maildir/
inet_protocols = ipv4, ipv6

# TLS
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
smtp_tls_security_level = yes
smtpd_tls_security_level = may
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.mydomain.org/fullchain.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.mydomain.org/privkey.pem

# Authentication
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous, noplaintext
smtpd_sasl_tls_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = $mydomain

# when mail location = maildir:~/.maildir
mailbox_transport = lmtp:unix:private/dovecot-lmtp
# Virtual user scenario
virtual_transport = lmtp:unix:private/dovecot-lmtp

biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

readme_directory = no

# See http://www.postfix.org/COMPATIBILITY_README.html -- default to 2 on
# fresh installs.
compatibility_level = 2
```

---

My Postfix `/etc/postfix/master.cf`

```
# ==========================================================================
# service type  private unpriv  chroot  wakeup  maxproc command + args
#               (yes)   (yes)   (no)    (never) (100)
# ==========================================================================
smtp      inet  n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
#smtp      inet  n       -       y       -       1       postscreen
#smtpd     pass  -       -       y       -       -       smtpd
#dnsblog   unix  -       -       y       -       0       dnsblog
#tlsproxy  unix  -       -       y       -       0       tlsproxy
submission inet n       -       y       -       -       smtpd
  -o smtpd_sasl_auth_enable=yes
  -o smtpd_sasl_type=dovecot
  -o smtpd_sasl_path=private/auth
  -o smtpd_sasl_security_options=noanonymous
  -o smtpd_sasl_local_domain=$myhostname
  -o syslog_name=postfix/submission
  -o smtpd_tls_security_level=encrypt
  -o smtpd_reject_unlisted_recipient=no
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
#  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=$mua_client_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=$mua_helo_restrictions
#  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=$mua_sender_restrictions
  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=reject_non_fqdn_recipient,reject_unknown_recipient_domain,permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
  -o smtpd_relay_restrictions=permit_sasl_authenticated,reject
  -o milter_macro_daemon_name=ORIGINATING
```

Netstat `sudo netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN`:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:4190            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      7055/dovecot        
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:993             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      7055/dovecot        
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:587             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      6999/master         
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:143             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      7055/dovecot        
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      6999/master         
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      657/apache2         
tcp6       0      0 :::4190                 :::*                    LISTEN      7055/dovecot        
tcp6       0      0 :::993                  :::*                    LISTEN      7055/dovecot        
tcp6       0      0 :::587                  :::*                    LISTEN      6999/master         
tcp6       0      0 :::143                  :::*                    LISTEN      7055/dovecot        
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      657/apache2         
tcp6       0      0 :::25                   :::*                    LISTEN      6999/master
```

---

**EDIT 1:**
I got this error for the command `openssl s_client -connect localhost:imaps`

```
write:errno=104
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 198 bytes
Verification: OK
---
```

But it turns out that I forgot `<` right before the `ssl_cert` and `ssl_key` path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Works as designed.**

That is precisely the purpose of the `smtpd_sasl_security_options=noplaintext` in postfix and `disable_plaintext_auth=yes` in dovecot. These options prevent (offering) authentication via insecure channels. You can verify that your server offers authentication via secured channels by initiating a secure SMTP connection:

```
$ (echo EHLO localhost; sleep 1) | openssl s_client -starttls smtp -connect localhost:submission
..
220 example.com ESMTP Postfix
..
250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
```

Same thing for a secure IMAP connection:

```
$ sleep 1 | openssl s_client -connect localhost:imaps
..
* OK [CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 .. AUTH=PLAIN AUTH=LOGIN]
```

**There is absolutely nothing wrong with having plaintext auth disabled. Just configure all your mail clients to access mail via TLS.** You might even want to disable plaintext IMAP to prevent mistakes.